# How to schedule a databricks notebook in Devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, databricks, azure-databricks

Below is the code I am using to schedule a Databricks notebook from devops pipeline.

```
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Schedule Databricks Notebook'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      personalAccessToken='dapie7'  
      databricksUrl='https://adb-13946.6.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0'
      notebookPath='/Users/notebook.py/'
      jobName='ScheduledJobName'

      requestUri="$databricksUrl/jobs/create"

      body='{
        "name": "'$jobName'",
        "new_cluster": {
          "spark_version": "7.0.x",
          "node_type_id": "Standard_DS3_v2"
        },
        "notebook_task": {
          "notebook_path": "'$notebookPath'"
        },
        "schedule": "@daily",
        "max_retries": 0,
        "timezone_id": "Canada/Eastern",
        "cron_schedule": "45 8 * * *"
      }'

      # Encode PAT to Base64
      patBase64=$(echo -n ":$personalAccessToken" | base64)

      # Make the API request
      curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic $patBase64" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "$body" "$requestUri"
```

This is my log.

```
Starting: Schedule Databricks Notebook
==============================================================================
Task         : Bash
Description  : Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
Version      : 3.229.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash /home/vsts/work/_temp/d7e8884a-073dfc.sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   402  100    54  100   348    277   1789 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2072
Finishing: Schedule Databricks Notebook
```

I do not see the job being created in the databricks. Is there any other way to schedule a job from devops pipeline or any corrections to the above code.

Thanks

Running a different notebook along with scheduling the 1st notebook.

```
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Schedule Databricks Notebook'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: | 
      
      databricksUrl='https://adb-13946046.6.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0'
      notebookPath='/Users/user/notebook1.py'
      notebookPath1='/Users/user/notebook2.py'
      

      jobName='ScheduledJobName1'
      jobName2='testjob'

      requestUri="$databricksUrl/jobs/create"
      requestUriRun="$databricksUrl/jobs/run-now"

      body='{
        "name": "'$jobName'",
        "new_cluster": {
          "spark_version": "7.0.x",
          "node_type_id": "Standard_DS3_v2",
          "num_workers": 0
        },
        "notebook_task": {
          "notebook_path": "'$notebookPath'"
        },
        "schedule": {
            "quartz_cron_expression": "45 10 * * * ?",
            "timezone_id": "Canada/Eastern"
        }
      }'

      body2='{
        "name": "'$jobName2'",
        "new_cluster": {
          "spark_version": "7.0.x",
          "node_type_id": "Standard_DS3_v2",
          "num_workers": 0
        },
        "notebook_task": {
          "notebook_path": "'$notebookPath1'"
        }
      }'

      # Make the API request
      curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $(token)" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "$body" "$requestUri"
      curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $(token)" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "$body2" "$requestUriRun"
```

Comment: Is notebook path mentioned is correct `notebookPath='/Users/notebook.py/'`?
Check it properly once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with below yaml and confirm it works:

```
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Schedule Databricks Notebook'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: | 
      databricksUrl='https://adb-1305924866893174.5.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0'
      notebookPath='/Users/user/Notebook1'
      jobName='ScheduledJobName1'

      requestUri="$databricksUrl/jobs/create"

      body='{
        "name": "'$jobName'",
        "new_cluster": {
          "spark_version": "7.0.x",
          "node_type_id": "Standard_DS3_v2",
          "num_workers": 0
        },
        "notebook_task": {
          "notebook_path": "'$notebookPath'"
        },
        "schedule": {
            "quartz_cron_expression": "45 8 * * * ?",
            "timezone_id": "Canada/Eastern"
        }
      }'

      # Make the API request
      curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $(token)" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "$body" "$requestUri"
```

Check on Databricks, the job is created:

[image]

1. Generate the token from Databriks, it's bearer type not basic. add the variable in pipeline:
   [image]
2. Add num_workers value as 0 for a single-node cluster.
3. cron syntax is different, please check [link](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the same pipeline along with scheduling one notebook can I just run a 2nd notebook without scheduling it. I tried it but it only schedules the first notebook.I have edited my code in the question.

Comment: It can, but run the job is totally a new query which is different with job schedule , you can raise a new ticket and share the link here, we can chat in that one. In order to let others who have the similar question with you know how you resolved it more clearly, please [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) according to How does accepting an answer work. Thanks!

Comment: Sure,here is the link. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77333272/how-to-schedule-a-databricks-notebook-and-run-a-different-notebook-from-the-same

thanks